# spring.net injection into a page

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, spring.net

Wondering if someone could help with with some Spring.net IOC integration into a .aspx page I have. At present the page is set up with controller ie. a Controller property is set with an object like so:

```
// Create a list of views
var views = new List<IView>() { this.MasterPage, this, this.ucHeader };

// Setup this page with a controller
this.Controller = new Controller(views);
```

What the above does is creates a list of Iview interfaces which is made up with a reference to the master page, current page and a header control which all inherit from IView. This is turn is passed in to the constructor of Controller object as shown above.

I want to move from this now and use Spring.net for IOC injection. Therefore with spring.net this will be achieved with xml files. I have this in place.

The problem I have is that I am not sure how I could about creating a list of the views, current, master page and ucHeader and passing to a Controller object.

Any advice on how I might achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?p=21861